# TouchUpInside Button Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have this code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        signInButton = CustomButton(frame: CGRectMake(12.5/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.width, 5/6.0 * self.view.bounds.size.height, 60, 23))
        signInButton.customizeButtonText("Sign in")

        joinButton = CustomButton(frame: CGRectMake((75/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.width), 5/6.0 * self.view.bounds.size.height, 60, 23))
        joinButton.customizeButtonText("Join")

        userNameTextField = CustomTextField(frame: CGRectMake(-500, 60/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.height, 400, 35))
        userNameTextField.placeholder = "Username"

        passwordTextField = CustomTextField(frame: CGRectMake(-500, 70/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.height, 400, 35))
        passwordTextField.placeholder = "Password"

        signInButton.addTarget(self, action: "signInButtonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        joinButton.addTarget(self, action: "joinButtonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}
```

Then in the `signInButtonClicked:` and `joinButtonClicked:` method I have this code where I animate the UITextField to the specific x and y position I want:

```
func signInButtonClicked(sender: UIButton!) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.25, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.userNameTextField.frame = CGRectMake((-500 + ((50/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.width) - 200)), 60/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.height, 400,35)
            }, completion: nil)
    }

    func joinButtonClicked(sender: UIButton!) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.25, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.passwordTextField.frame = CGRectMake((-500 + ((50/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.width) - 200)), 70/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.height, 400,35)
            }, completion: nil)
    }
```

For some reason whenever I click on `signInButton` or the `joinButton` the animation of the textfields do not happen. Am I doing something wrong here? I added the target for both of the buttons to self and set the correct action for each of the buttons.

CustomButton Class:

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: SHAWDOW_COLOR, green: SHAWDOW_COLOR, blue: SHAWDOW_COLOR, alpha: 0.5).CGColor
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 2.0)
        self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "NotoSans-Regular", size: 17.0)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    func customizeButtonText(text: String!) {
        self.setTitle(text, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
joinButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("joinButtonClicked:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)`
```

instead of

```
joinButton.addTarget(self, action: "joinButtonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: It does not make any difference in Swift if you write `Selector("joinButtonClicked:")` or just `"joinButtonClicked:"`.

Comment: I tried using that as well. But it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Make sure that your buttons have `userInteractionEnabled` and also all their superviews.

Comment: That didn't seem to fix the problem either :(

Comment: Also if you use a custom button and you add some subviews to it disable user interaction on the subviews to prevent them from intercepting the touch.

Comment: I have update my question with the Custom Button class. Also I do not have any subviews on my custom button. Just a normal button.

Comment: Okay, never mind. I added some print statements in the selector methods for the button and the click on the button is working perfectly fine. It is now actually the animation of the textfield that is not working. Can you please take a look at that animation code I write in my two method?

Comment: what do you want the animation to look like?

Comment: I want the two textfield which are originally at a x position of -500 to slide in from the left of the screen to the very middle. So -500 + (1/2 * self.view.bounds.size.width).

Comment: did you try `self.passwordTextField.center = self.view.center`?

Comment: Use `self.userNameTextField.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.width / 2.0, self.userNameTextField.frame.origin.y)`

Comment: Still did not work... :(. Is my animation CurveEaseInOut correct?

Comment: `self.userNameTextField.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.userNameTextField.center.y)`

Comment: just one quick and silly question: do you add the textfields to your view hierarchy somewhere? :)

Comment: Use view debug to check where are your textfields before and after the animation. You can open view debug by tapping the button which looks like three rectangles just below your code panel in xCode. After that in view debug panel there is a button that allows you to see the views outside your screen.

Comment: omg... I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake. I am very sorry for wasting your time over such a trivial solution haha... I never added the textfield to the view as a subview....

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip Jelly! I will definitely check that out. Never knew that existed...

Comment: @KB3 no worries. glad we could figure it out... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is (speak: *should be*) working; what is not working is the way you set up the animation location within those action methods.

By looking at the way you set up the initial positions of the `UITextFields` and the post-animation position, I came to the understanding that you would like the `UITextFields` to be initially off-screen and would then animate on-screen once the buttons are clicked.

Given that, the problem lies in the following lines of code:

```
self.userNameTextField.frame = CGRectMake((((-500 + 50/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.width) - 200)), 60/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.height, 400, 35)

self.passwordTextField.frame = CGRectMake((((-500 + 50/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.width) - 200)), 70/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.height, 400,35)
```

Logging these numbers, one would see that:

```
NSLog("%f", (-500 + ((50/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.width) - 200)))

-512.500000
```

The functions do work and so do the animations; it is just that you are animating the `UITextField` from a position that was initially off-screen to, well, again another that is off-screen.

By simply changing the lines to the following within the animation blocks, respectively:

```
self.userNameTextField.frame = CGRectMake((((50/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.width) - 200)), 60/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.height, 400, 35)

self.passwordTextField.frame = CGRectMake((((50/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.width) - 200)), 70/100.0 * self.view.bounds.size.height, 400,35)
```

allows us to see that the `UITextField` do come into the screen, once the buttons are clicked.

Comment: Oh ok! Yes that worked perfectly. The thing is that my textfield is still cut off. from the left and right. What would be the proper way to fix this? Just make a width of each of the textfields shorter or add constraints through code?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, I just calculated the width of the textfield based on the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Check current and parent view controllers on:

1. Touch bounds must be in view frames.
2. view.userInteractionEnabled. They must be `true`.

Comment: Can you please explain what "Touch bounds must be in view frames." means? How do I check that?

Comment: Touch events trigger in bounds collisions.